# React Hook - tsx and untyped array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm learning Hooks, and trying to use typescript at the same time.

How do I get rid of this error? How to add Item type properly to useState()?

[image]

**HookCounter.tsx**

```js
import React from 'react'
import {useState} from 'react'

interface Props{}
interface Item{
    id: number;
    value: number;
}
interface Person{
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}


const HookCounter : React.FC<Props> = () => {//S1 create functional component
    //S3 : method capable of setting that state var
    const initialCount = 0
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0) // this hook accepts initial val, and returns current val, and 
    
    const [name, setName] = useState({firstName : '', lastName: ''}) // Ch 4: object in useState
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]) // Ch 5: array in useState



    const incrementFive = () =>{
        setCount( prevCount => prevCount+5)
    }

    const addItem = () => {
        setItems([ ...items, //copy prev array for merge
            {
                id: items.length
                , value: Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1
            }//newitem
        ]) //setItems
    }//addItem
    return (
        <div>
            Ch 3: Using previous state: <em> setCount(prevCount => prevCount +1)</em>
            Count : {count}<br/>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount +1)} > More + </button><br/>
            {/* For incrementfive no ()=> */}
            <button onClick={incrementFive} > More +5 </button><br/> 
            <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount -1)} > Less - </button><br/>
        
            <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)} > Reset </button>
            <hr/>
            Ch 4: Using useState with object: <em>useState(json-object)</em><br/>
            Manual merge with spread operator: <em>onChange= e = setName( ...name, firstName : e.target.value )</em>

            <form>
                {/* TODO check why should I mention both firstname and lastname in setname() */}
                <input type="text" value={name.firstName} onChange={e => setName({ ...name, firstName : e.target.value })} /><br/>
                <input type="text" value={name.lastName} onChange={e => setName({ ...name, lastName : e.target.value })} /><br/>
                
            </form>
            Your first name is: <em>{name.firstName}</em><br/>
            Your last name is: <em>{name.lastName}</em><br/>
            state variable name : {JSON.stringify(name)}
            <hr/>
            Ch 5: Using useState with arrays: <em>useState(json-object)</em><br/>
            
            <button onClick={addItem}>Add a number</button>
            <ul>
                {items.map(item => (
                    <li key={item.id}> {item.value} </li>
                ))}//items
            </ul>
        </div>
    );//return
};
export default HookCounter;
```

Answer (score 1):

specifies the state type

```
const [items, setItems] = useState<Item[]>([]) // Ch 5: array in useState
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this.
docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate
it has callback with previous state params inside

```
setItems(previous => ({...previous, 
  id: items.length, 
  value: Math.Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1}))
```